# How to display value labels above graph bars using chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using chart.js,i want to  show the label value above the bars, so how do it?

```
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and decided to write it.  Please get my version of chart.js from my forked version on github: [Chart.js](https://github.com/kerbasaurus/Chart.js)

You can pass the following options:

```
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  }]
};
var opts = {
    scaleShowValues: true, 
    scaleValuePaddingX: 13,
    scaleValuePaddingY: 13
};
var chrt = document.getElementById('chrtDemo').getContext('2d');
new Chart(chrt).Bar(barChartData, opts);
```

scaleValuePaddingX and scaleValuePaddingY will shift the value position so you can fine-tune it.

You can also pass a dataset of colors to color each bar individually:

```
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: ["rgba(220,220,220,0.5)", "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)", "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)"],
    strokeColor: ["rgba(220,220,220,1)", "rgba(220,220,220,1)", "rgba(220,220,220,1)"],
    data: [65, 59, 90],
  }]
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I had to hardcode the X position of the values. The scaleValuePaddingX doesn't work

Comment: @nach Sorry, I haven't rewritten this for the newest version of Chart.js.  This works for the version I needed at the time.

Comment: no problem, thanks for doing it. BTW did you know how to prevent the rotation when the labels are too long? I want to put them in two lines. Thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose this functionality has been added to the master chart.js, has it?