# How to change color of labels in bar chart using chart.js

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

Currently, I am developing a bar chart using chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org).
But I don't know how to change color of labels of the chart.
Please refer to the image below:

[image]

So, I need to change the color of 'January', 'February' and the value: '0', '5', '10' and so on.

I have read the documentation about it, but it seem doesn't has option to change the labels color (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart).

Any ideas?
Thank You!

Comment: When you draw the chart set the option `scaleFontColor` to a color, this will color the labels of the graph, [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/zyn9w64k/). Note the solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513023/change-label-font-color-for-a-line-chart-using-chart-js).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: can I use for bar chart? the question looks like for line chart. Oh, sorry. I just read your other comments. Thank You. It solved my question.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Hi Spencer, do you have any idea how to change color of value above the bar. Please refer to image: http://i.imgur.com/alL5fcb.jpg. As you can can see, value '563', '531', etc still in default color. Do you have any ideas how to change the color? Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind creating a fiddle (you can use mine as a starting point), to show me how you are putting the values above the bars?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Hi Spencer, I don't know how to show you in fiddle. But I refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856209/how-to-display-value-labels-above-graph-bars-using-chart-js.